# Why .replace method doesn't work this way?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace

I want to clear all the whitespaces in the string `arrayIsNowJoined`, and everywhere I look up target the solution I have...but it just doesn't work. I got the following code:

```
const array1 = ["1, 3, 4, 7, 16", "1, 2, 4, 16"];
let arrayIsNowJoined = array1.join();

arrayIsNowJoined.replace(/\s/g, "");
console.log(arrayIsNowJoined);
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must assign variable after replace

> arrayIsNowJoined = arrayIsNowJoined.replace(/\s/g, "");

Comment: I see this happen very often, even with seasoned developers. Somehow devs expect the original variable to be modified without reassignment.

Answer (score 2):

You need an assignment of the result, because strings are immutable.

```js
const array1 = ["1, 3, 4, 7, 16", "1, 2, 4, 16"];
let arrayIsNowJoined = array1.join();

arrayIsNowJoined = arrayIsNowJoined.replace(/\s/g, "");
console.log(arrayIsNowJoined);
```